# How does recursion work on traversing through a binary tree, and counting the number of list nodes?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree, traversal

I have trouble visualizing these following print and size functions from the following URL (https://repl.it/@flowerplowedup/SquigglyVerifiablePaint#main.c):

Comment: It is more complicated than a simple linked list: it is a tree. For any given node, the function `print_ascending()` follows items less than `root->value`, prints `root->value` and then follows items greater than `root->value`. Similarly, the function `size()` sums the linked items less than `root->value`, adds `1` for `root->value` and then follows items greater than `root->value`. When a link is `NULL` there is nothing to count or follow so it returns `0`.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you find confusing?  Recursion is all about breaking a problem up into smaller, similar problems. (For example, the size of a tree is the combined size of its subtrees plus the current node.)

Comment: I just have trouble visualizing recursion :( And thanks @Weather-Vane for mentioning it's on BSTs, not linked lists; it seems like recursion on linked lists would be easier for me to visualize.

Comment: A diagram of a simple tree with about 7 nodes (depth 3) would be worth many words. Not too many nodes to be confusing when you look at it with pencil and paper.

Comment: @Budding_Programmer For starters the program has undefined behavior because the pointer root was not initialized.

Comment: The diagram of [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) will help. Be sure you understand the difference between a general "Binary Tree" and a [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) - the ordering is important.

Comment: It looks like you have accidentally removed most of the information in your post. I assume you are currently busy editing. Please make sure that you restore the question so that the existing answer remains applicable. I will undo the deletion in a while, if there is not corresponding improvement by you.

Comment: I undid the seemingly accidental edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you enter the input sequence

```
4 8 2 7 9 1 3 -1
```

You wind up with a tree that looks like this:

```
                           4
                          / \
                         /   \
                        2     8
                       / \   / \
                      1   3 7   9
```

`print_ascending`'s execution will look something like this :

```
print_ascending( node(4) )
{
  node(4) != NULL
  print_ascending( node(4)->left == node(2) )
  {
    node(2) != NULL
    print_ascending( node(2)->left == node(1) )
    {
      node(1) != NULL
      print_ascending( node(1)->left == NULL )
      {
        NULL == NULL
        return
      }
      print( 1 )
      print_ascending( node(1)->right == NULL)
      {
        NULL == NULL
        return
      }
      return
    }
    print( 2 )
    print_ascending( node(2)->right == node(3))
    {
      node(3) != NULL
      print_ascending( node(3)->left == NULL )
      {
        NULL = NULL
        return
      }
      print( 3 )
      print_ascending( node(3)->right == NULL )
      {
        NULL = NULL
        return
      }
    }
    print( 4 )
    print_ascending( node(4)->right == node(8) )
    {
      node(8) != NULL
      print_ascending( node(8)->left == node(7) )
      {
        node(7) != NULL
        print_ascending( node(7)->left == NULL )
        {
          NULL == NULL
          return
        }
        print( 7 )
        print_ascending( node(7)->right == NULL )
        {
          NULL == NULL
          return
        }
        return
      }
      print( 8 )
      print_ascending( node(8)->right == node(9) )
      {
        node(9) != NULL 
        print_ascending( node(9)->left == NULL )
        {
          NULL == NULL
          return
        }
        print( 9 )
        print_ascending( node(9)->right == NULL )
        {
          NULL == NULL
          return
        }
        return
      }
      return
    }
    return
  }
  return
}
return
```

Hopefully that helps visualize what's going on, and what's going on in the `size` function as well.  Recursion's one of those concepts that takes a while to wrap your head around.

Comment: @Budding_Programmer the `size()` function begins at the root node, which asks the node on its left how many nodes there are on that side. So node 2 says hang on, I have to ask the guys on my left and my right how many nodes they link to. Those each reply `1` if you follow it through, and node 2 returns `1` from its left plus `1` for self plus `1` from its right `= 3` to the root node. So root node now asks the node on its right how many there are that way and gets the answer `3` by the same process. Finally root node reports `3` from its left plus `1` for self plus `3` from the right `= 7`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped a lot.